# NPAPI debugging with logging proxy / MitM

Tags: debugging, proxy, npapi, man-in-the-middle

I'm debugging/hacking on a NPAPI browser plugin and I'd like to log/wiretap communication between the browser and the plugin, to know exactly what the plugin is doing. Do you know if there is an existing tool for it? I found none.

My motivation is to a) analyze the plugin and to b) evaluate security of it.

I think it should be generally possible as a Man-in-the-Middle, i.e. a wiretapper which would act a) as a plugin to the browser and b) as a browser to the plugin, and just pass on all commands (method calls). Thus pretty straightforward and easy solution.

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that the browser/plugin communication is a pretty small part of what many NPAPI plugins do. For example, security holes in plugins are often a function of the calls they make directly to platform APIs, not the interaction with the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an existing utility for this, but it would be relatively straight-forward to build.
You'd basically just need to register your plugin instead of the original and implement and forward the `NP_*`, `NPN_*` and `NPP_*` functions.

Another approach would be to just trace the calls from the browser-side (via [logging already possible in parts](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/base/nsPluginLogging.h) or just [tracing via symbol server and debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server)), but then you will probably have to worry about some differences in code-paths for in-process vs. out-of-process-plugins.

Comment: Another option for your specific plugin (but not generic) would be to just add file-based logging to all of your NPN_ methods; I've been intending to build a tool such as you describe for a long time, but I just haven't had time to do so.

Comment: @taxilian: I understood that he wanted to analyze a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: Ahh; I think you're correct.  I missed that reading through the first time.

Comment: @taxilian: I think you meant NPP_ methods, right? NPN_'s are in the browser which I can't change.

But as Georg pointed out, I'm analyzing a 3rd party plugin which I can't edit.

Comment: Actually I meant both; if you set up a proxy like Georg suggests you'll want to log in both places. However, all of the NPN_ functions are just wrappers that call the function pointers given to you by the browser, so you can easily add log statements in the wrapper

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Thanks for the links, logging in firefox looks great and I'm able to log (probably) all NPN_ functions logged. However, I'm getting very few logs from NPP_ functions, cannot figure out why :/

Comment: @juzna.cz They might not get logged in all code paths - i haven't looked it over in detail, so i'm not sure about that.